# Storing strings in JSON::Any variables not working

Tags: crystal-lang

I recently got back into crystal and I noticed some breaking changes concerning JSON behaviour in 0.25.0.

Previously, when I had a variable of type `JSON::Type`, I could simply store a string in it

```
a : JSON::Type
a = "some string"
```

this is no longer possible after changing the variable `to JSON::Any`, resulting in an error: `type must be JSON::Any, not String`

However, calling `.to_json` or `as(JSON::Any)` on the string also does not work because the returned value is also of class `String`.

```
puts typeof("Hello".to_json) => String
puts typeof("Hello".as(JSON::Any)) => String
```

Is this intended behaviour? How do I now store strings in json?

Also, locally, for `JSON.parse("some string")` I get a `JSON::ParseException`, while it works online...
https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/4y49

Comment: ah, I just noticed that 'JSON::Any.new("some string")' works. So I guess that's the required usage now?

Comment: It might be that you're not using the API as intended, wanting to declare the type of a local variable is a red flag in Crystal in general. Could you provide a more full-fledged example?

Comment: You can post your first comment as answer and accept it. `JSON::Type` as union type has been replaced by `JSON::Any` which is a struct wrapping a JSON value. This simplifies a lot of things, including avoiding recursive aliases. See https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/pull/5183 for details.

Comment: Code inside `typeof` will not be executed. It is just used to statically analyse the return type. Running `JSON.parse("some string")` (outside of `typeof`) fails as expected: https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/4y8v

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage is now `JSON::Any.new("some string")`